# NNJoin not returning any result

Tags: qgis

I am trying to run NNjoin plugin on a point layer (one layer, so a selfjoin) to find nearest neighbour, but the joined layer it produces has 0 features in it. The original points layer has 32000 features.
I tried to use distance matrix which worked, but I want to retain the original attributes, which is the benefit of NNjoin.
Does anyone know why this might be? I don't get any error messages.
I am using EPSG:27700 if that is important.

Comment: To clarify, is your desired output a shapefile with the original features that also contains a field with the ID of the nearest neighbor from the same set of features?

Comment: yes, as you usually would with nnjoin. I have done it before with other data so not sure why it isn't working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run NN join directly on the layer by setting both the input and join fields to that layer. The output will consist of the original geometry with new fields in the attribute table that relate each feature to it's nearest neighbor, including the distance in map unites (meters in your case).

**Original data:**

[image]

**NNJoin interface:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is what I have done, but the attribute table is completely empty. I have added photos

Comment: Can you try to run the tool on a small subset of your points? I have a feeling the issue could be with the number of features in your layer and the less than optimal memory allocation by the NNJoin tool.

Comment: Tried running nnjoin on a sample of 300 of the points, and the same thing happened where the joined layer was empty

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what happens - but if you have input and output the same layer, then no lines at all are created since each point is connected just with ifself. Might that be the problem?

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: In theory, you should be able to use the same layer for both inputs using NNJoin.  Like in the example from Kartograaf.

Comment: I don't think I can share the data sorry!

Comment: OK, try this then, create a new point shapefile layer using EPSG:3857, then add new geometries to that layer that mimic the locations of 5 or 10 of your points, then save the layer and try running the tool on the new layer in the same way as above. Be sure to label the ID fields with unique integers as you create them or after the fact.

Comment: Tried this, and nnjoin worked (as in, there were features in the output) but the distances were completely off for most of the points

Comment: The distance discrepancy is related to the datum component of the coordinate and reference system (units, cartesian vs. ellipsoidal distance calculation, etc..) but I think your issue may lie with the original dataset.

Comment: problem solved- the layer I'm using was the result of a previous spatial join a while ago. Deleting all the old attribute columns in the table from previous join made nnjoin work. Probably something obvious i should have noticed.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Happy to help, please upvote and/or accept answer if you feel like it was on-track.